# How to configure a static IP address in the local network for a Ubuntu VM?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, ipv4

I am using a Windows 10 laptop connected to the internet via Wifi. On it I run a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 20.04.5.

As I want to connect to the internet AND to the local network I plan to configure two network adaptors as layed out below. I especially want to be able to ping `8.8.8.8` and to ping a device in the local network with the IP address `192.168.200.10`. On the Windows host I can ping the two addresses without any issues.

### Adaptor 1 Configuration

#### VirtualBox Config

- NAT
- Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (AM79C973)
- Cable connected is checked

#### Guest Config

- IPv4: DHCP
- IPv6: Automatic

[image]

### Adapter 2 Configuration

#### VirtualBox Config

- Host-Only Adapter
- Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (AM79C973)
- Cable connected is checked
- Tools -> Host-only Network:

[image]

#### Guest Config

- IPv4: Manual
- IPv6: Disable

[image]

### Results

#### Adapter 2 disabled

[image]

When I only have Network Adapter 1 enabled I can ping both addresses from the VM, `8.8.8.8` and the local device under `192.168.200.10`.

#### Adapter 2 enabled

[image]

When I enable the Network Adapter 2, to which I configured a *local* IP address in the *local* network, I would expect that I also can ping both IP addresses.

But as it turns out, I only can ping `8.8.8.8`, and *not* the IP address in the *same* local network, `192.168.200.10`!

### Questions

1. I appreciate if a network expert can explain me in detail what is going on, ideally in lame terms, so I can understand.
2. Also I would like to know how I can fix this problem, i.e. to configure the VM in such a way that (i) I can ping the outside world (i.e. `8.8.8.8`), (ii) I can ping the device in the local network (i.e. `192.168.200.10`) and (iii) to assign a fixed IP address to the VM so the VM can be pinged in the local network setup.

Thanks a lot

### Additional information

#### ipconfig of host machine

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64a6:b4ee:7b73:aa63%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.44
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-Verbindung* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-Verbindung* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::978c:ae31:388b:1086%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.1

Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:cb16:9:1946:333a:61e4:9de4:bd4e
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a01:cb16:9:1946:5fc:6037:3f84:8a32
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c2a:e902:799d:9451%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.249.238
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::f4d8:35ff:feb4:93c5%8
                                       192.168.249.79

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::be63:31b4:cebb:e898%64
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.29.64.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to configure two adapters in order to connect the VM to the intranet and the internet. Simply making it part of your intranet, which has access to the internet, should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the *same* local network. You've created *two* networks, which only happen to use identical IP numbering but there is nothing that actually connects them. Unlike switch ports, multiple interfaces on a host or a router remain independent subnets by default – packets can be forwarded between them using routing (but each would need to use different addressing for routing to work), or the interfaces can be bridged together using the "bridge" feature in Windows (but I'm not sure whether it works with VirtualBox virtual interfaces).

If you want the VM to be attached to your physical Ethernet subnet (the existing 192.168.200.0/24 network), just select **Bridged** mode in VirtualBox (and delete the Host-Only adapter).

Comment: So you are saying I should just use ONE adaptor and make it bridged?

Comment: In the post I'm saying that you should switch Adapter #2 from "Host-Only" to "Bridged" mode – but, yes, it would be enough to have _just_ the "Bridged" adapter without the "NAT" one.

Comment: It seems your suggestion does not work. I configured the VM to have only one Bridged Adaptor, and set the manual IP address to 192.168.200.100. I still can ping `8.8.8.8` but not `192.168.100.10` anymore.

Comment: I overlooked that you have Wi-Fi and Ethernet connected to separate networks. For that to work you'll still need two adapters – #1 for internet access (either NAT or Bridged to Wi-Fi), #2 for LAN access (Bridged to Ethernet).

Comment: I now set adapter 1 to NAT and adapter 2 to Bridged, with IP address `192.168.200.100`. I am able to ping `8.8.8.8`, but I cannot ping `192.168.200.10` from within the VM. Something still mist be wrong. Also, I still cannot ping the VM under the address `192.168.200.100` from the Windows Host. When I deactivate adapter 2, THEN I can ping `192.168.200.10`.

Comment: Did you attach the "bridged" adapter to the correct physical adapter? And did you delete the old "host-only" adapter from Windows?

Comment: @John: That's straight up nonsense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142495/discussion-between-alex-and-user1686).

Comment: I changed adapter 2 to bridged. Not sure what you mean by "attach" the adapter to the physical adapter...

Comment: I mean [this parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idWle.png). The "bridged" adapter has to be bridged to _something_ – you have to select one of the physical network interfaces that your host has.

Comment: It says "Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160 MHz". Not sure how a virtual device can have WiFi. I guess this is the wrong setting...

Comment: Finally! Maybe it works now. I just tried all of these adapters. Now it seems to work. 
Can't the VirtualBox figure out these things on its own? Why do I have to configure every tiny bit? This is tremendous complicated! I mean, for example, how do I figure what interfact my host has?